# js, make a json object a string - the easy way?

Tags: javascript, json, string

I have tried lots of different ways, and using many diffent PHP and JS functions to try to achieve this.
Hoe to i turn this json object ;

```
"lines" :   ["text line 1<br/>","text line 2<br/>","text line 3<br/>","text line 4<br/>"]
```

Into this string, so that i can add to a HTMl div

```
text line 1<br/> text line 2<br/> text line 3<br/> text line 4<br/>
```

No, quotes, brackets or anything else.

In it's simplest form all i have is stringify;

```
lines = JSON.stringify(obj.lines)
```

but the above outputs, brackets, quotes, and commas

Sorry if this is a simple and silly question, but i h (finishing now (embarrassed!)) ave searched everywhere for a simple answers. Nothing stands out.

Comment: I guess we should give you 5 minutes to finish your question? ;) .... *Sorry if this is a simple and silly question, but i h......................*

Comment: There are no "JSON objects". What you have is an array.

Comment: `"lines" :   ["text line 1<br/>","text line 2<br/>","text line 3<br/>","text line 4<br/>"]` is not a JSON object. Did you mean `{"lines" :   ["text line 1<br/>","text line 2<br/>","text line 3<br/>","text line 4<br/>"]}`, which is an object? Do you have an object or a JSON string?

Comment: Nah. It is an object. Not "JSON object". The only JSON object you really have in browser is the one that have .parse property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
var html = obj.lines.join("");
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/VXbs7/

Comment: @GodLesZ: Which is good, since that's not what the question is asking for.

Comment: I think I'm missunderstood the question, sorry.

Comment: @GodLesZ, The OP's exact words are *so that i can add to a HTMl div*. So he clearly needs the tags too. Andrew is right. +1

Comment: Thats it!!! :) As simple as i needed it to be. Sorry, but i wanted to maintain the tags. And apologies for my lack of correct use for JSON terminology, just coming up to scratch with it all

Answer (score 0):

You *have* a JSON string. You need to *parse* it into a data structure, then get the array of strings, and loop over them (outputting as you go).

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this from javascript, it's quite easy.  JSON is native to javascript and can be interpreted as an object quite simply.  It looks like you only have half your JSON object pasted in your question though.  A whole JSON object is wrapped in `[]` or `{}` (unless it's just a string or number type, but then it's not an object).

Anyway, if you're in PHP - you can easily `json_decode()` this string and loop it like so:

```
<?php
$arr = json_decode($json_string, true); //true makes it an array instead of object

foreach ($arr['lines'] as $line)
{
    echo $line;
}
```

If you're trying to accomplish it in javascript (in the browser), it's also quite easy (assuming your string is stored in a php variable, and that you're using jquery for dom manipulation)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var obj = <?= $json_string; ?>,
    mydiv = $('#mydiv);

for (key in obj['lines'])
{
    var line = obj['lines'][key];
    mydiv.append(line);
}
</script>
```

both of those should give you the output you're looking for

Comment: OP wants to strip the tags too. "No, quotes, brackets or anything else."

Comment: @GodLesZ: No, the OP wants to keep the tags.

Comment: As I understood (which might have been wrong, i think we can all agree that the question could be worded better) the OP didn't understand how to utilize a JSON string as an array or object, and wanted to get rid of the quotes around the strings, the square brackets around the array, the commas between the elements, etc.  This led me to believe that he didn't understand how to turn the string into a json object/php array in order to make use of it; hence - the answer (:

Comment: Right Jim, i'm new to Json, so i dont understand it all but y'now i'll get there. And my apologies for not wording correctly. I guess this is why we post here, to learn from others. :)